# Writing A Macro in Access to save and export to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

This is the final leg of a project I am working on, I have a form which writes/edits data to a table in access, I am trying to write a macro on the form that saves the data and then exports to the table in sql server. I have already established the connection between access and sql, I am just not good at the coding part. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, people react badly to request to write code. Perhaps you can do a little research and post back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to this is to create an append query that will append the record your form just saved (to the local table) from the local table to the linked server table. Then use a macro tied to the After Insert event on your form to run the append query.

Comment: I have it setup to where the form auto writes to the table. I am looking for help writing code that saves and exports the data to the linked sql table.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a linked table, linked to the SQL Server table, and do your export from Access as you would to your Access table.

Comment: I do have it linked, but I am trying to write a macro that saves the data then uploads the data to the table on the SQL server